# mongodb - concat array field from many documents to one array field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this query:

```
 [
  {
    '$match': {
      'imageUrls': {
        '$type': 'array', 
        '$ne': []
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'imageUrls': 1, 
      'time': 1
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      'time': 1
    }
  }, {
    '$skip': 0
  }, {
    '$limit': 10
  }
]
```

This is the schema:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ffb0c14dd482daa039ee906"
    },
    "imageUrls": ["image url1", "image url2"],
    "time": 342432432432
}
```

The output is a list of documents, each containing the array field `imageUrls`.
I want to have all the values in the `imageUrls` fields in one single array field.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266590/merging-array-fields-in-mongodb-aggregation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$sort` by time in descending order
- `$project` to show only one field `imageUrls`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `imageUrls` array
- `$facet` to separate both result, total and pagination documents
- `$skip` documents
- `$limit` number of documents
- `$group` by `null` and reconstruct `imageUrls` array

```
  { $sort: { time: -1 } },
  { $project: { imageUrls: 1 } },
  { $unwind: "$imageUrls" },
  {
    $facet: {
      result: [
        { $skip: 0 },
        { $limit: 10 },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            imageUrls: { $push: "$imageUrls" }
          }
        }
      ],
      count: [
        { $count: "count" }
      ]
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lfEDJmVWill)

Comment: I want to sort the results by time, so when exactly should I use these stages inside mine, or maybe I should move the $sort stage to somewhere earlier?

Comment: so the skip and limit I should put right before the group, right?

Comment: And how do I get the total count of all urls, ignoring the $skip and $limit?

Comment: You should add the `$limit` before the `$sort`, because the resulting documents must not exceed the BSON Document Size limit of 16 megabytes.

Comment: @RonyTesler i have updated answer, i hope you have no more questions after this.